# Python to reshape dataframe using pivot. Index does not appear

Tags: python, pivot

I am trying to reshape my data frame using the pivot function. I want that 'name' is the index, columns as 'month' and 'sum' for values. However my index doesn't appear in output when I run the code below

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'name': ['apples', 'orange', 'apples',  'banana', 'strawberry'],

'month': ['jan18', 'jan18', 'feb18', 'feb18','jan18'],

'sum': [56, 75, 32, 98, 12]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = df.pivot_table(index=['name'], columns=['month'], values=['sum'], 
aggfunc=[np.sum], margins=True)
```

out:

```
sum sum sum
sum sum sum
feb-18 jan-18 All
 32     56      89
  .......
```

I want the following:

```
       feb-18 jan-18
apples  32     56
orange
  .......
All .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['apples', 'orange', 'apples',  'banana', 'strawberry'],
                   'month': ['jan18', 'jan18', 'feb18', 'feb18','jan18'],
                   'sum': [56, 75, 32, 98, 12]})


print(df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='month', values='sum', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0, margins=True))
```

This prints out:

```
month       feb18  jan18  All
name                         
apples         32     56   88
banana         98      0   98
orange          0     75   75
strawberry      0     12   12
All           130    143  273
```

If you want to save to CSV:

```
pivoted.to_csv(path_or_buf='d:/work/pivoted.csv')
```

This will produce a file with content:

```
name,feb18,jan18,All
apples,32,56,88
banana,98,0,98
orange,0,75,75
strawberry,0,12,12
All,130,143,273
```

Comment: Still does not work for me.  It uses the month - feb18- as the index and not the column 'name'

Comment: @thor I am using Python 3.6. What about you? Did you import numpy like I did?

Comment: @thor Please check the updated answer. I am also not using lists as the parameters for index, columns, values and aggfunc which you are doing.

Comment: Thanks it works. I needed to specify when saving to csv that index=True

When I save to csv, the column headers are 'sum'. Do you know how I get the month only?

Comment: @thor something like: df.to_csv(path_or_buf='d:/work/pivoted.csv'). Check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html . Index is true by default by the way.

Comment: thank you. when i save to csv now. the headers are 'sum' how do I change that to month i.e. the column headers are 'jan18', 'feb18', etc. And also how do I put month in chronicle order ascending?

Comment: @thor you can re-index the columns, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40125810/2735286

Comment: @thor If this answer solved the problem in the question, please accept it. The purpose of the answer is not to solve all your problems you might encounter.