# Swap contents of columns inside dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with this contents;

```
Column1   Column2    Column3  
C11         C21        C31
C12         C22        C32
C13         C23        C33
```

I would like to swap the contents between Column 1 and Column 2.

The output dataframe should look like this;

```
Column1   Column2    Column3  
C21         C11        C31
C22         C12        C32
C23         C13        C33
```

I am using python v3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to swap two DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649429/how-to-swap-two-dataframe-columns)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better answer, but you can swap the column names and then reorder:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Column1": ["C11", "C12", "C13"],
                   "Column2": ["C21", "C22", "C23"],
                   "Column3": ["C31", "C32", "C33"]})
df.columns = ["Column2", "Column1", "Column3"]
df[["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"]]
```

Comment: This is a nice way to tackle it. Although you can make use of a function etc. eg `df.rename(lambda x: x.translate(x.maketrans('12','21')),axis=1).iloc[:,[1,0,2]]`