# Python/Pandas: Sort dataframe columns based on a column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing several columns labelled x1, x2, x3, and x4.

Depending on the analysis, I would need to assign one of the four columns to be the first column when ordering the four columns in the dataframe from left-to-right.

For instance, if I want column 'x2' to be the first I assign it to 'sorter'.

```
sorter = x2
```

Now my question: how I sort the dataframes in the column so that the column assigned to 'sorter' is located in the first column?

EDIT: The order of the rest of the columns should remain unchanged.

Comment: isn't this function what you want to use? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: what is the order of the other columns? does it not matter

Comment: `df.sort_values(['x2','x1','x3','x4'])`?

Comment: and you can use that to swap the columns of your dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652061/5228292

Comment: if you don't specify the other columns, it won't sort them. I'm not sure if it uses a stable sorting algorithm, so the order in the rest of the columns might be random

Comment: by default it uses quicksort, you can use mergesort to have stable sorting (i.e. relative order in the rest of the columns for the same keys in the sorted column will stay the same)

Comment: you could also have a look at [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/) [reorder](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.reorder_columns.html#janitor.reorder_columns) or [move](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.move.html#janitor.move) functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change order of columns like:

```
data = {'X1':  ['11', '12'],
        'X2': ['21', '22'],
        'X3': ['31', '32']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
    X1  X2  X3
0   11  21  31
1   12  22  32

df = df.reindex(['X3','X1','X2'], axis=1)
df

    X3  X1  X2
0   31  11  21
1   32  12  22
```

Note : You need to provide desired order.

You can create a function to change order by given column:

```
def sorter(desired, df):
    columns = df.columns.tolist()
    columns.remove(desired)
    columns.insert(0,desired)
    return df.reindex(columns, axis=1)

sorter('X2',df)

    X2  X1  X3
0   21  11  31
1   22  12  32
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to assign the column that I want as 'first column' to a variable (like in my post) and have the order of the rest of the columns remain unchanged?

Comment: Hope the sorter function helps. It change first column as given and keep rest of them the same.