# How do I swap rows/columns in csv python

Tags: python, csv

My raw csv file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ6nn.png).

```
ID,SCORE1,SCORE2
1101110061,50,75
70,1101110062,80
85,52,1101110063
```

How do I swap `score1` and `score2` into the `ID` column?

I want to like this :

```
ID,SCORE1,SCORE2
1101110061,50,75
1101110062,70,80
1101110063,52,85
```

Using csv or pandas but csv is preferred.

Comment: What you want to do is there rule for swapping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to swap two DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649429/how-to-swap-two-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Please do not post images when you could post text. Furthermore, a csv file is not a spreadsheet format (whatever Excel can pretend) but a **text** format. If you show the file as text, we can see what the delimiter is and whether fields are quoted, and can easily copy and paste the data to reproduce. If you want a relevant answer to your question please show the file as text.

Comment: ... With what you have shown I can only say: read the file with the csv module **using a configuration that I cannot know so I cannot propose any code** one row at a time, and write it to a new file still one row at a time after swapping the relevant fields in the row. But I will not write code that I cannot test against your data...

Comment: @SergeBallesta sorry, i've been updated in to the text data

Comment: It would also be a bit clearer if you also added what your expected output for your example would be

Comment: @MartinEvans ah sorry, i've been update it

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, the ID has the largest value and the scores then appear to be sorted. As such you could sort each row by their integer values and then take the largest (last) value as the ID and then the remaining values as the scores. For example:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        sorted_row = sorted(map(int, row))  # convert to integers and sort
        csv_output.writerow([sorted_row[-1], *sorted_row[:-1]])
```

```
ID,SCORE1,SCORE2
1101110061,50,75
1101110062,70,80
1101110063,52,85
```

---

If you just want to change the column order:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    data = list(csv.reader(f_input))
    
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    
    for row in data:
        csv_output.writerow([row[1], row[2], row[0]])
```

Giving you:

```
SCORE1,SCORE2,ID
50,75,1101110061
1101110062,80,70
52,1101110063,85
```