# switch column locations in python datatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

What is the most efficient way to switch the locations of two columns in python datatable? I wrote the below function that does what I want, but this may not be the best way, especially if my actual table is big. Is it possible to do this in place? Am I missing something obvious?

```
from datatable import Frame
dat = Frame(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6],c=[7,8,9])

def switch_cols(data,col1,col2):
    data_n = list(data.names)
    data_n[data.colindex(col1)], data_n[data.colindex(col2)] =  data_n[data.colindex(col2)], data_n[data.colindex(col1)]
    return data[:, data_n]

dat = switch_cols(dat, "c","a")

   |     c      b      a
   | int32  int32  int32
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 |     7      4      1
 1 |     8      5      2
 2 |     9      6      3
[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

For comparison in R, we can do this

```
dat = data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(7,8,9))
switch_cols <- function(data,col1,col2) {
  indexes = which(names(dat) %in% c(col1,col2))
  datn = names(dat)
  datn[indexes] <- datn[c(indexes[2], indexes[1])]
  return(datn)
}
```

Then, we can change the order of two columns **in-place** like this

```
setcolorder(dat, switch_cols(dat,"a","c"))
```

Please note that assigning the values to each column is not what I'm after here.  Consider this example, in R.  I construct a large data.table like this:

```
dat = data.table(
  x = rnorm(10000000),
  y = sample(letters, 10000000, replace = T)
)
```

I  make two copies of this data.table `d` and `e`

```
e = copy(dat)
d = copy(dat)
```

I then compare these two in-place operations

- setcolorder (simply reindexing where in the data.table two columns are)
- `:=` re-assignment of the two columns

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  list=alist("setcolorder" =  setcolorder(d, c("y", "x")),
             "`:=`" = e[,`:=`(x=y, y=x)]),
  times=1)

Unit: microseconds
        expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
 setcolorder    81.5    81.5    81.5    81.5    81.5    81.5     1
        `:=` 53691.1 53691.1 53691.1 53691.1 53691.1 53691.1     1
```

As expected, `setcolorder` is the right way to switch column locations in R `data.table`.  I'm looking for a similar approach in python.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that in place.  You can do it while copying:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649429/how-to-swap-two-dataframe-columns

Comment: Basically move column C to column a position and vice versa?

Comment: that's right @sammywemmy, I'm feeling pretty silly at this point. thanks for your patience..

Comment: No, it's all good. `dat[:, ['c','b','a']]`? I don't think  a copy is made here, but I might be wrong ; you can ask on the GitHub page though

Comment: yeah, that is what my `switch_cols` function is doing

Comment: run a timeit on `dat[:, ['c','b','a']]`, you can increase the number of rows to millions and see the performance,the timings should generally be constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some consideration and timings, I'm finding that the best approach is this:

```
from datatable import Frame
dat = Frame(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6],c=[7,8,9])

   |     a      b      c
   | int32  int32  int32
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 |     1      4      7
 1 |     2      5      8
 2 |     3      6      9
[3 rows x 3 columns]



def switch_cols(data,col1,col2):
    return data[:, [col1 if c==col2 else col2 if c==col1 else c for c in data.names]]

switch_cols(dat, "a","c")

   |     c      b      a
   | int32  int32  int32
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 |     7      4      1
 1 |     8      5      2
 2 |     9      6      3
[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a method after checking its document

```
from datatable import Frame,f,update
dat = Frame(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6],c=[7,8,9])

dat[:,update(a = f.c, c = f.a)]
```

In R, you can do it similarily

```
dat[,`:=`(a = c, c = a)]
```

Comment: thanks for your response. These move the values from c in to column a, and the values from a into column c.  I was simply asking how to relocate the columns, in-place.  Maybe I'm overthinking this, and it is as simple as doing this, plus renaming the columns in a second step