# What is the most efficient way to swap the values of two columns of a 2D list in python when the number of rows is in the tens of thousands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

for example if I have an original list:

```
A B 
1 3
2 4
```

to be turned into

```
A B 
3 1
4 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to swap two DataFrame columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649429/how-to-swap-two-dataframe-columns)

Comment: List or dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

two cents worth:

3 ways to do it

1. you could add a 3rd column C, copy A to C, then delete A.  This would take more memory.
2. you could create a swap function for the values in a row, then wrap it into a loop.
3. you could just swap the labels of the columns.  This is probably the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df2 = df.rename(columns={'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'})
```

output:

```
   B  A
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

If order matters:

```
df2 = df.rename(columns={'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'})[df.columns]
```

output:

```
   A  B
0  3  1
1  4  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with dictionary for swapping columnsnames, last check orcer by selecting columns:

```
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns[::-1])))[df.columns]
print (df)
   A  B
0  3  1
1  4  2
```

Comment: @mozway - I wainting 2 minutes

Comment: No worries, just letting you know. I was editing when I saw your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just simple use `masking` to change the `values`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2],"B":[3,4]})

df[["A","B"]] = df[["B","A"]].values

df

   A  B
0  3  1
1  4  2
```

Comment: That doesn't swap the values

Comment: True. I edited it, so it does now.

Answer (score 0):

for more than 2 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9], 'D':[10,11,12]})
print(df)
'''
   A  B  C   D
0  1  4  7  10
1  2  5  8  11
2  3  6  9  12
'''
df = df.set_axis(df.columns[::-1],axis=1)[df.columns]
print(df)
'''
    A  B  C  D
0  10  7  4  1
1  11  8  5  2
2  12  9  6  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your list is like this:

```
my_list = [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

So you can use this code:

```
print([[each_element[1], each_element[0]] for each_element in my_list])
```

The output is:

```
[[3, 1], [4, 2]]
```